# Is it good practice to use the event object to access an html node in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

Is it good practice to use the event object to access an HTML node in react?

exam:

```
function MyComponent() {

function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        //use event object to access html node
        console.log(e.target.name.value)
    }

return (
      <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input name='name'>
          </form>
      </div>
       )
}
```

Or should I use a reference?

```
function MyComponent() {

let textInput = useRef(null)

function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(textInput.current.value)
    }

return (
      <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input ref={textInput} name='name'>
          </form>
      </div>
       )
}
```

It is easier to use the event object to access the node, but is it good practice, is it recommended?

Comment: Accessing it directly from `e.target.value` is fine, no need add complexity with a ref.  There is nothing inherently wrong with that.  It is also common to make it a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), and have the value being store in a state variable, in which case, you would just use the state variable in your handleSubmit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no problem with reading event objects until you don't modify the DOM contents directly because react can't notice that and this will cause some problems...